# Problem with nested FOR-Loop and IF-Condition

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, substring

I have some lines of text. Then I have a list with test-words. I like to look up each line of the text and check if one of the test-words appears in it.
Beforehand this works well with a commands like these:

`IF not "!stringToTest:%searchstring%=!"=="!stringToTest!"`

However, now this seems to be more complicated as I have nested Loops?

I try to create a little MWE for my problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counterPC=0
set "listPC=Win10,Motherboard,USB-Port,Core"
FOR %%G in (%listPC%) do (
    set PCsearchVal[!counterPC!]=%%G
    set /a counterPC+=1
)
set /a counterPC-=1
set "dummyline=Environment,1234,ZUIOP,Core"
FOR %%G in (%dummyline%) do (
    set "stringToTest=%%G"
    echo String to Test: !stringToTest!  
    FOR /l %%I in (0,1,%counterPC%) do ( 
        set "searchstring=!PCsearchVal[%%I]!"
        echo Test for this String: !searchstring!
        IF not "!stringToTest:%searchstring%=!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Searchstring is in String to Test
    )     
)
endlocal
pause
```

In this he alway enter the IF-Condition. I know that this can may be solved with `FINDSTR` however in all my other code I used the search-strategy liek above. There may be just a little mistake I oversee? Many thanks in advance-

Comment: Doe this question supercede your previous two? If so please delete those two questions. Alternatively, delete this one, and one of the others and edit the remaining one, to bring it on topic with a clearly defined issue and sufficient code for us to replicate that issue.

Comment: @Compo sorry for this, I did delete my previous questions. In my shown MWE code the problem I mentioned appears

Comment: As a side note, change your search-strategy to use [tag:findstr] instead.

Comment: Here's a basic three line example: **1.** `@Set "listPC=Win10,Motherboard,USB-Port,Core"`, **2.** `@Set "dummyline=Environment,1234,ZUIOP,Core"`, **3.** `@For %%# In (%listPC%)Do Echo("%%#"|FindStr /IL "\"%dummyline:,= %\"">NUL&&(Echo Searchstring %%# is in String to Test&Pause)`.

Comment: Thank you @Compo !!

Comment: SRel, if you're satisfied with the example in my comment, would you like me to make it an answer for you to accept?

Comment: @Compo there is one last thing I am struggeling with: the '''FOR''' iterate through listPC and I can output each element. However I may also want to output each element of '''dummyline''' also. Trying ''' echo "\"%dummyline:,= %\""   ''' give me no ouput. How to access one of the element of '''dummyline''' as you did?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no intention of answering new questions or modifying the code I provided in my comment. I'm afraid I will not be providing a solution in the answer area for this change.

Comment: Okay no problem. You can post your comment as an anwer so I can mark it as answered as it solved my initial problem. Many thanks for this.

Comment: `if not "!stringToTest:%searchstring%=!"=="!stringToTest!" ...` cannot work when `searchString` is changed in the same block of code; you cannot use `!searchString!` of course as you cannot nest delayed expansion; but you can use a `for` loop: `for %%S in ("!searchString!") do if not "!stringToTest:%%~S=!"=="!stringToTest!" ...`...