# Variables are not set properly inside nested loops

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, find, substring

I have a similiar question like I did ask here: [Nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197886/problem-with-nested-for-loop-and-if-condition)

However, I still did not solve the "problem" which seems to be little. I already implemented the solution mentioned using `[FindStr][2]`, however the runtime is much much longer than without FindStr. So I would like to keep the method using

`IF not "!stringToTest:!searchValue!=!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Something`

Below I post some runable  code. In the beginning I just set my array with the values I would like to search for and then some exmaple "texts" in which I like to search my beforehand set searchvalues.
My strategy:

1. Loop through my file with the text lines. For each line test each SearchValue for presence.
2. After all Searchvalues tested, go to ne next line and check also for the presence of each searchvalue.

So I have two nested Loops. At every step inside the loop I output the current vaule of the variables and those seems to be correct. I really do not know how my fault in this line is as the searchfunction is not working correctly:

`IF not "!stringToTest:!searchValue!=!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Searchword is in Textline`

There may be just a little mistake in here? I am very thankful for every tipp in this issue.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
set "searchValues=abc,xyz"
FOR %%G in (%searchValues%) do (
    set arraySearchVal[!counter!]=%%G
    set /a counter+=1
)
REM set arraySearchVal
set /a counter-=1
set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"
FOR %%G in (%TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%) do (
    set "stringToTest=%%G"
    echo Textline:         !stringToTest!   
    FOR /l %%I in (0,1,%counter%) do ( 
        set "searchValue=!arraySearchVal[%%I]!"
        echo Searchword:       !searchValue!
        REM echo !stringToTest! found in Textline | findstr "!searchValue!"
        IF not "!stringToTest:!searchValue!=!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Searchword is in Textline
    )
    echo/     
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: You cannot do double delayed variable expansion. IE: `"!stringToTest:!searchValue!=!"`

Comment: You have made this difficult on yourself by making that array. Why not make the first `FOR` command the nested `FOR` command to get the search strings.  Then you can use: `IF not "!stringToTest:%%I=!"=="!stringToTest!"`

Comment: thank you, so you mean why I just not swap my two for-commands but keeping both?

Comment: No.  I mean get rid of the existing nested `FOR /L` command and use the first `FOR` command as your nested `FOR` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This falls under the K.I.S.S. methodology. By making your search arguments array variables you have over complicated your code.  You can simplify it like so.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "searchValues=abc,xyz"
set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"

FOR %%G in (%TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%) do (
    set "stringToTest=%%G"
    echo Textline:         !stringToTest!   
    FOR %%I in (%searchValues%) do ( 
        echo Searchword:       %%I
        IF not "!stringToTest:%%I=!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Searchword is in Textline
    )
    echo/     
)
endlocal
pause
```

If you really want to use your original code you can get the double variable expansion using a trick with the `CALL` command to set another variable. Then use that variable with the `IF` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
set "searchValues=abc,xyz"
FOR %%G in (%searchValues%) do (
    set arraySearchVal[!counter!]=%%G
    set /a counter+=1
)
REM set arraySearchVal
set /a counter-=1
set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"
FOR %%G in (%TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%) do (
    set "stringToTest=%%G"
    echo Textline:         !stringToTest!   
    FOR /l %%I in (0,1,%counter%) do ( 
        set "searchValue=!arraySearchVal[%%I]!"
        echo Searchword:       !searchValue!
        REM echo !stringToTest! found in Textline | findstr "!searchValue!"
        call set "temptest=%%stringToTest:!searchValue!=%%"
        IF not "!temptest!"=="!stringToTest!" echo Searchword is in Textline
    )
    echo/     
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getring into this too much, why are you creating a list of counter values if you don't need to?  Why bot loop the 1st set and 2nd set wirhoutbhaving special variables for a for L loop, as you don't then assign the positional value.

Another bit, are all of the terms you are looking to see if exist in the text strings partials?  Or are you always going to match the full string?   If you are matching full strings you only need one loop.

IE if possible strings to match are the Full value, or "whole word" you want to find in the set to look through.

EG

```
REM this sees if any of the arguments match the list of options using only one loop.
Set "_OptionsToMatch= -D -Delete -R -Remove "
FOR %%_ in (%*) DO (
  Echo=%_OptionsToMatch% | FIND /I " %%~_ " )
```

### Assuming the above doesn't work for you in this scenario for some reason

Well lets address the other bits like why are you crwating a valued array at all?

```
@(echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "searchValues=abc,xyz"
  set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Pause
  Exit /B
)

:Main

 FOR %%G in (%TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%) do (
     SET "stringToTest=%%G"
     FOR %%g in (%searchValues%) do (
       IF /I "!stringToTest:%%g!" NEQ "%%G" (
         Echo The string "%%G" contains "%%g"
       ) ELSE (
          Echo The string "%%G" does not contain "%%g"
       )
    )
  )
Goto :EOF
```

If all that were needed you could amend the above to make it work to have numbered arrays as it goes along I suppose.

### Alternatively if you just want to address what is going on:

Delayed expansion isn't a complete replacement for calling a command or using a function.

This is one of the reasons Inused to only write scripts wirhout delayed expansion as even wirh it on mor complex work still requires calling a function to do the steps as part of the loop.

This is generally when doing lots of value man up such as here.

The alternative, which works as well is to create loops to do the next level of variable manipulation, which is faster?  YMMV

Which is simpler - generally calling the sub function.

Which is easier to follow - YMMV.

Here is the sub function method:

```
@(echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set /a "counter=0"
  set "searchValues=abc,xyz"
  set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Pause
  Exit /B
)

:Main

  FOR %%G in (%searchValues%) do (
    set /a "counter+=1"
    set "arraySearchVal[!counter!]=%%G"
  )


  FOR %%G in (
    %TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%
  ) do (
      set "stringToTest=%%G"
      echo Textline:         !stringToTest!   
      FOR /l %%I in (1,1,%counter%) do ( 
        Call set "searchValue=!arraySearchVal[%%I]!"
        echo Searchword:       !searchValue!
        CALL :Fn_Compare
        If !_CmpResult! == 0 (
          Echo=the string did not exist.
          Echo=Even in your loop you can use this result now.
        )  ELSE (
           Echo=the string does exist.
           Echo=Even in your loop you can use this result now.
        )
      )
     echo/ 
  )
Goto :EOF

:Fn_Compare
  REM echo !stringToTest! found in Textline | findstr "!searchValue!"
  IF /I "!stringToTest:%searchValue%=!" NEQ "!stringToTest!" (
    echo Searchword is in Textline
    Set "_CmpResult=1"
  ) ELSE (
    Set "_CmpResult=0"
  )
Goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this not all you need?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TextWhichNeedToBeSearched=tzu,abc,qsd"
Set "SearchValues=abc,xyz"
Set "ResultString=Searchword is in Textline"

For %%# In (%SearchValues%)Do (
    Echo Textline:         %TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%
    Echo Searchword:       %%#
    Echo("%TextWhichNeedToBeSearched%"|FindStr "\<%%#\>">NUL 2>&1&&(
        Echo(%ResultString%)||Echo(%ResultString:is=is not%
    Echo(
)
Pause
```