# Exit a loop when a value was found

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, exit

I have a file with several lines:

`"pathToFile=%~dp0PBreport\cpy\Install\"`

More, I have a list of strings with different search values:

`"searchValue=abc,there,rtz"`

My aim is to search each line of the file for the occurence of a search value and then execute some code. However, if maybe the first element in my list of search values is found it is not necesseray to check the other values.
I do the whole thing with a nested foor loop, however when I implement something like `GOTO` the outer loop do not continue. Is tehre some mistake using GOTO inside a loop? Or is there a better way to exit and skipp all other checkings if one was already found?
The complete Code work without problem without the `GOTO`statement.

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in (%pathToFile%) do (
  set "dataRow=%%~G"
  FOR %%I in (%searchValue%) do ( 
      IF not "!dataRow:%%I=!"=="!dataRow!" (
      ### some Code here ###
      GOTO endIfCases
      )
  )
  ###some similiar blocks like the one above which can also be ignored if one match was found beforehand###

  :endIfCases
  ### some Code which needs to be excecuted at the end of each loop from the outer FOR###
)
```

Comment: The `GOTO` command does what it is programmed to do. Go to a predefined label in your code and begin executing from there.  That will break out of any `FOR` commands you are executing.

Comment: that is what I wanted it do do. However it seems that he also do not continue the outter loop FOR /f as my ouput only has one value

Comment: As I said it breaks **ANY** `FOR` **commands** you are executing.  You will need to CALL to a label to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ah I understand, okay I will try doing so thank you

Comment: Remember when I provided you [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197886/problem-with-nested-for-loop-and-if-condition#comment104617111_59197886) one week ago? _Here's a basic three line example: **1.** `@Set "listPC=Win10,Motherboard,USB-Port,Core"`, **2.** `@Set "dummyline=Environment,1234,ZUIOP,Core"`, **3.** `@For %%# In (%listPC%)Do Echo("%%#"|FindStr /IL "\"%dummyline:,= %\"">NUL&&(Echo Searchstring %%# is in String to Test&Pause)`_. How far is that away from what you're now asking?

Comment: @Compo I tried this with ```FindStr```however for some reasons the runtime is was too long. it could be that I did not implemented it well. my problemw as that I do not know exactly how findsdtr works "inside". besides this i am very thankful for your answer

Comment: @SRel, I don't believe that `FindStr` is slower than any of the methods you're attempting! In fact from my own tests of the past, I'd suggest that it was possibly one of the quickest methods, and that any problem was more than likely caused by information you have withheld. When suggesting tools and/or methodologies for a task, we can only base it on the data you provide. Why not therefore take a step back, provide us with some genuine data which you have determined `FindStr` is too slow to process and we should be able to provide more focused/useful advice.

Comment: @SRel, to find out how almost any command, or executable which accepts options, works, open up a Command Prompt window, and enter its name followed by `/?` i.e. `findstr /?`

Answer (score 2):

This solution is simple and efficient:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in (%pathToFile%) do (
  set "dataRow=%%~G"
  set "break="
  FOR %%I in (%searchValue%) do if not defined break ( 
      IF not "!dataRow:%%I=!"=="!dataRow!" (
      ### some Code here ###
      set "break=1"
      )
  )
  ###some similiar blocks like the one above which can also be ignored if one match was found beforehand###

  ### some Code which needs to be excecuted at the end of each loop from the outer FOR###
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you arrange your code something like this (passing parameters to subroutine as needed):

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in (%pathToFile%) do (
   CALL :YourSubr "Parm1" "Parm2"
     ### some Code which needs to be excecuted at the end of each loop from the outer FOR###
)
GOTO :eof

:YourSubr
REM 1=???
REM 2=???
set "dataRow=%%~G"
FOR %%I in (%searchValue%) do ( 
   IF not "!dataRow:%%I=!"=="!dataRow!" (
   ### some Code here ### using passed parameters
   )
)
```

I see you are using delayed expansion but your code does not show the SETLOCAL... so be careful with where your ENDLOCAL is placed.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants to _cancel_ the processing of the rest of values after one was not found. Your solution process all values always... Perhaps you forgot a `GOTO`? **;)**